# ! Too many }'s.\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup \end{figure}

Tags: graphics, floats, color, minipage, document-classes

```
%======================================================================
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%            SPECIFICATION FOR COMMON IEEE STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                    Janardan Kundu
%======================================================================

\documentclass[
    %draft,
    submission,
    %compressed,
    %final,
    ]{ieee}
%\documentclass[AMS,stixtwocol]{WileyNJD-v1}

\newcommand{\latexiie}{\LaTeX2{\Large$_\varepsilon$}}
\usepackage{cite}
\graphicspath{{./pics12/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
%\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%\doublespace
\onehalfspacing
%\singlespacing
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%\hyphenation{optical net-works semi-conductor IEEEtran}

\begin{document}


 \begin{figure} [!htb]
   \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
         \epsfig{file=17_03.png, scale=1.37}
      \caption{Steel plate (148 $gm$)}\label{17_03}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   \epsfig{file= hhhhh.png, scale=0.4}
      \caption{Photograph of the proposed levitated system}\label{hhhhh}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Too many }'s.\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup \end{figure}
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{figure}
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What is your question?

Comment: The `epsfig` package has been obsolete for almost 30 years. Use `graphicx` and `\includegraphics`.

Comment: ieee class is also obsolete.  The most recent version available on CTAN is IEEEtran.  The newest one has to be downloaded directly from IEEE, nor does it come with a manual.

Comment: Please trim this down to the minimal code that you think should work but still generates that error.